# Return multiple serialized models. Stops serializing when adding to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I am using:

- active_model_serializers 0.10.8
- ruby 2.5.3p105
- Rails 5.2.1.1

Serializer:

```
class CarSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :make, :model
end
```

If I do this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cars = Car.all

    render json: @cars
  end
end
```

Then my API returns as expected, just the make and model attributes (not ID or timestamps). All good.

If I change my controller to:

```
@cars = Car.all

render json: {
  cars: @cars
}
```

It no longer uses the serializer and returns the full model (id, make, model, timestamps).

I am trying to do this as I want to return multiple models, ie:

```
render json: {
  cars: @cars,
  drivers: @drivers
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Why doesn't it serialize when I add it to the hash?

Newbie to ruby and rails, apologies for any stupid mistakes!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, it should be:

```
render json: {
      cars: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(Car.all),
      drivers: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(Driver.all)
}
```